# Reflect change of libraries affecting all google spreadsheets using the library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google spreadsheets and I am attempting to make use of libraries.

I just want to update a function in my library and then have the change affecting all spreadsheets using the library.

Is there a way I can do that without having to increment the version and go into every single spreadsheet script to include the recent version?

**EDIT :** Is there a way to do this without using the development mode? I want to only publish the new version to the spreadsheets when it is stable. So when version 2 is ready i would like to batch update all the dependent spreadsheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "development mode"